# Using the $\epsilon-K$ definition of the limit of a sequence, prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{6n^3-1}{3n^3-n-1}=2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Using the $\epsilon-K$ definition of the limit of a sequence, prove that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{6n^3-1}{3n^3-n-1}=2$$

So what I've done is the usual technique

$$\left| \frac{6n^3-1}{3n^3-n-1}-2 \right| \space =\space\left| \frac{2n+1}{3n^3-n-1} \right|$$

Now I need to establish the upper bound. This is the part I'm not very sure of. usually I arrive at a term of degree $1$ for $n$. but in this case I seem to get a degree of $2$. Does it still work?

i.e.

$$\left| \frac{2n+1}{3n^3-n-1} \right|\space \le \space \frac{3n}{4n^3}=\frac{3}{4n^2}$$

I'm also wondering if I could set the upper bound farther.

i.e.
$$\left| \frac{2n+1}{3n^3-n-1} \right|\space \le \space \frac{3n}{4n^3}=\frac{3}{4n^2} \le \frac{3n}{4n^2} = \frac{3}{4n}$$

This way I can set $K\ge\frac{3}{4\epsilon}$.

Comment: If you insist you can have $\frac{2}{3n}< \epsilon$. However your answer is correct!  Good job!

Comment: Two degree is fine.  Better even.  Can take K > 3/4sqrt (eps).  Or you can do what you did.  Works just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: For large enough $n$,

For numerator, use $|2n+1|\le 3n$

For denominator, use $|3n^3-n-1|=|2n^3+n^3-n-1|\ge 2n^3\ge 2n^2$

Then we have $$\bigr| \frac{2n+1}{3n^3-n-1} \bigl|\space \le \space \frac{3n}{2n^2}=\frac{3}{2n}$$

---

Also, I think for your method, you need to provide more justifications about why this inequity holds
$$\bigr| \frac{2n+1}{3n^3-n-1} \bigl|\space \le \space \frac{3n}{4n^3}$$